# MongoDB: Replace entire documents if exist, otherwise remove it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new with MongoDB and Im using it to store data from peeringdb.com (webscraping).

An example of input at day 1:

```
  {
    "ip_range": "45.227.3.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "2822"
  },
  {
    "ip_range": "200.219.130.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "1684"
  },
  {
    "ip_range": "187.16.202.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "790"
  },
  {
    "ip_range": "45.227.2.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "3096"
  }
```

I get it with a python script save it do a dict and insert into mongodb with:
`collection.insert_many(dictionary_example)`

Let's suppose that in another day (day2) my script run and get this data in my `dicionary_example2`:

```
  {
    "ip_range": "45.227.3.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "0002"
  },
  {
    "ip_range": "45.227.2.0/24",
    "id_ptt": "0001"
  }
```

It means that the ip "200.219.130.0/24" and "187.16.202.0/24" is removed, and that the ID of other two is updated to 0002 and 0001. How to reflect this change in my MongoDB? I know if I use `collection.drop` and after `collection.insert_many(dictionary_example2)` I will get the result that I want, but I guess this is not the right approach, because if someone use my mongodb to query between the moment of drop and insert will get no results, right?

Im not sure if I should use replaceOne or update_many() and which filter to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the date with each document.

When querying, provide the most recent date that you know was processed.

Comment: Does upseart works also removing documents if doens't find?

Comment: No, store the date of each document for that.

Comment: instead of replace, I'm always inserting documents with the date of each document insertion as you said. 
And when i want to search (query) I filter $gte today. What do you think about it? Its a good approach? And I need to delete it after storing one week for example, because it will be bigger by time

Comment: Not gte today, equal to the most recent date that was fully ETLed.

Answer (score 0):

update_many() has worked for me in previous scenarios with mongo